# How to properly constrain this hold time?

Tags: fpga, quartus, intel, sdc

I am puzzled, can't get to any seemingly simple and, what's more important, solution looking correctly.

There's a main fast clock, `fclk`, and I divide it by 4, getting `sclk`.
There's internal IP block in the FPGA which must be driven at the `sclk` frequency, and I recall it needs 50/50 duty cycle.
The design has `sclk_negedge` signal, which I use to latch input and output registers to/from that block, which is internally being driven by the posedge of the sclk, therefore there is surely half of the `sclk` cycle between me setting registers and block getting their outputs.

But Quartus, and it is logically, does not understand it without specific instruction (which I am looking for) and sees minimal delay between `fclk` and `sclk` and reports hold violation.

The report looks like this

```
from node: r_in_register
to node: (some reg recipient buried within the target block)
launch clock: fclk
latch clock: sclk
relationship: 0.000
skew: 4.296
data delay: 0.795
```

The code is something like this

```
wire fclk;
reg [2:0] div;
reg sclk;
reg prev;
reg sclk_negedge;

always@(posedge fclk) begin
    sclk_negedge <= 1'b0;
    div[2:0] <= div[2:0] + 1'b1;
    if(div[2] ^ prev) begin
        sclk <= ~sclk;
        if(sclk) sclk_negedge <= 1'b1;
    end
    prev <= div[2];
end

//-------------

reg [3:0] inreg;

ip block {
    .clock  (sclk),
    .data   (inreg[3:0])
};

always@(posedge fclk)
    if(sclk_negedge)
        inreg[3:0] <= somedata[3:0];
```

Regarding the problem I am trying to solve: the IP clock needs lower frequency, and does not have clock enable, and I recall (can't find it right now) that it needs 50/50 duty cycle, therefore just feeding `fclk` with clock enable won't work. I have checked the sources of it, and it seems to only use posedge of the input clock, however then I am not sure why there might be a requirement for 50/50...

Answer (score 0):

From your description of how the clocks are used, I believe this is the timing diagram.

[image: Setup-Hold Relationship]

Notice that because `sclk` is an integer fraction of `fclk`, it doesn't actually matter whether you are using the rising or falling edge of `sclk`, the hold relationship will always be zero, because every edge of the slower clock will occur at a corresponding rising edge of the fast clock (*).

Quartus has therefore correctly determined the hold relationship to be 0.

---

(*) Assuming both have 50% duty cycle, and a 0 degree phase relationship.

Comment: Thanks. The IP block is clocked by the posedge of `sclk`. Input registers for this block are clocked at `fclk` but only at negedge of `sclk`. The difefrence is that I clock input registers 1/2 of `sclk` earlier than they are consumed by the IP block.

Comment: @Anonymous could you draw a rough timing diagram? How are you ensuring that only the specificfast clock edge is used?

Comment: edited the question adding the code